# No se descargan bien los PDF en el Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, grocery-crud, ckeditor

Estoy utilizando Grocery Crud, tengo un campo de tipo text y cuando añado o edito sale un ckeditor, lo cual es perfecto. Mi problema es cuando visualizo estos datos, las imágenes, textos, no tengo problemas, pero si pongo para que se descargue un pdf o un .rar, la dirección que me sale es la que le pongo en el ckeditor, pero detrás de toda la dirección de la pagina.

**Ejemplo:**

**dirección PDF:** `assets/pdf/test.pdf`

**dirección en la vista:** `localhost/codeigniter/index.php/admin/text_page/assets/pdf/test.pdf`

**Información adicional**

Con el grocery crud guardo los datos en la Base de Datos, (EN UN SOLO CAMPO), o sea, en este campo está todo lo que quiero mostrar, texto, imagen, incluyendo el PDF, cuando voy a la vista donde muestro este campo, las imágenes se ven bien pero el url del PDF no.

Necesito que no salgan ni el controller ni la funcion.
Gracias de antemano.

Comment: **[Bienvenida a Stack Overflow en Español](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour)**. lee 
**[cómo crear una buena pregunta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)**. **Debes [edit] tu pregunta** con el código que hayas intentado, errores, etc. Si no sabes cómo hacer lo que describes en tu pregunta, investiga primero y actualiza tu pregunta con los enlaces de la investigación que hayas hecho. Hasta que no añadas mas información, es posible que tu pregunta quede en espera-[¿Qué significa si una pregunta está "cerrada" o "en espera"?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions).

Answer (score 0):

Buen día. Puedes utilizar el `base_url();` en tu aplicación de codeigniter en la carpeta `config/` en el archivo **config.php** buscas la variable `$config['base_url']` y colocas la dirección de tu aplicación:

```
$config['base_url']='localhost/codeigniter/';
```

Y en tu controlador llamas a tu método por el base_url asi:

```
base_url('admin/text_page/assets/pdf/test.pdf');
```

Ahora bien tambien puedes manejar un archivo htaccess como este:

```
# Customized error messages.
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php

# Set the default handler.
DirectoryIndex index.php

# Various rewrite rules.

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /codeigniter/index.php/$1 [L]

</IfModule>  
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  <FilesMatch "\.(ttf|ttc|otf|eot|woff|font.css|css)$">
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
  </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
php_value upload_max_filesize 30M
php_value post_max_size 30M
php_value max_execution_time 1000
php_value max_input_time 1000
```

Comment: si, visualizar imágenes, archivos en la vista normalmente no es un  problema para mí. La cuestión es que con el grocery crud guardo los datos en la Base de Datos, (EN UN SOLO CAMPO), o sea, en este campo está todo lo que quiero mostrar, texto, imagen, incluyendo el PDF, las imágenes se ven bien pero el PDF no.